# Multiple Visitors on related classes

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, visitor-pattern

I'm simplifying things to point out my basic design problem.

I have an hierarchy like this:

```
              R                <-- interface
            /   \
           /     \
          /       \
        BR         RR          <-- abstract classes
      / | \       / | \
     /  |  \     /  |  \
  BRA BRB BRC  RRA RRB RRC     <-- classes
```

where `BRA`, `BRB`, `BRC`, `RRA`, `RRB` and `RRC` are classes that need to be visited.

I also have two visitor classes, who don't share any common ancestor class (for now). So, finally, the code is structured like this:

```
public interface R {
    /* . . . */
}

public abstract class BR implements R {        
    /* . . . */        
    public abstract void accept(VisitorBR vbr);
}

public abstract class RR implements R {
    /* . . . */
    public abstract void accept(VisitorRR vrr);
}


public class BRA extends BR {
    /* . . . */
    public void accept(VisitorBR vbr) { vbr.visit(this); }
}

public class BRB extends BR {
    /* . . . */
    public void accept(VisitorBR vbr) { vbr.visit(this); }
}

public class BRC extends BR {
    /* . . . */
    public void accept(VisitorBR vbr) { vbr.visit(this); }
}


public class RRA extends RR {
    /* . . . */
    public void accept(VisitorRR vrr) { vrr.visit(this); }
}

public class RRB extends RR {
    /* . . . */
    public void accept(VisitorRR vrr) { vrr.visit(this); }
}

public class RRC extends RR {
    /* . . . */
    public void accept(VisitorRR vrr) { vrr.visit(this); }
}
```

and

```
public class VisitorBR {
    /* . . . */
    public void visit(BRA r) { /* . . . */ }
    public void visit(BRB r) { /* . . . */ }
    public void visit(BRC r) { /* . . . */ }
}

public class VisitorRR {
    /* . . . */
    public void visit(RRA r) { /* . . . */ }
    public void visit(RRB r) { /* . . . */ }
    public void visit(RRC r) { /* . . . */ }
}
```

---

The client class has a `BlockingQueue<R>`, and one reference to an object of each visitor class, and needs to handle all elements of the queue using the most suitable visitor. Looks like this:

```
public class Client implements Runnable {
    private VisitorBR vbr;
    private VisitorRR vrr;
    private BlockingQueue<R> q;

    /* . . . */

    @Override
    void run() {
        for (;;) {
            R r = q.take();

            /*** Somehow handle r with the most suitable visitor, ***/
            /*** based on whether it's descendant of BR or RR. ***/

        }
    }
}
```

What would be the most elegant solution for this? By the way, in any case, the visitors must not be nested classes, and I'm trying to avoid using `instanceof`.

My workaround is to define `public static final` enum fields in abstract classes `BR` and `RR` to distinguish them, and use an `if` block, something like this:

```
@Override
void run() {
    for (;;) {
        R r = q.take();

        if (r.getType() == BR)
            ((BR) r).accept(vbr);
        else // if (r.getType() == RR)
            ((RR) r).accept(vrr)
    }
}
```

But there has to be a more elegant solution to combine two visitor classes than this.

Comment: I think you're looking for Double Dispatch. See https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/java/2.

Comment: @AdiLevin I'm aware of this source, I just couldn't adjust it to my case.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think I've figured something better for now, *inspired* by the [Selective Visitor Pattern, as described here](http://www.educery.com/papers/patterns/visitors/selective.visitor.html). However, I'm still open to elegant solutions.

A new class `SelectiveVisitor` is defined, which now is the sole reference to a visitor class that `Client` owns. Interface `R` now declares an additional method:

```
public interface R {
    /* . . . */
    public accept(SelectiveVisitor sv);
}
```

So, `BR` and `RR` are modified like this:

```
public abstract class BR implements R {        
    /* . . . */
    public void accept(SelectiveVisitor sv) {
        sv.visit(this);
    }
    public abstract void accept(VisitorBR vbr);
}

public abstract class RR implements R {
    /* . . . */
    public void accept(SelectiveVisitor sv) {
        sv.visit(this);
    }
    public abstract void accept(VisitorRR vrr);
}
```

The new class is defined like this:

```
public class SelectiveVisitor {
    private VisitorBR vbr;
    private VisitorRR vrr;

    public SelectiveVisitor(VisitorBR vbr, VisitorRR vrr) {
        this.vbr = vbr;
        this.vrr = vrr;
    }

    public void visit(R r) {
        // this method should never be called in practice 
        // it's here only to satisfy the selective visitor pattern
        return;
    }

    public void visit(BR r) {
        r.accept(this.vbr);
    }

    public void visit(RR r) {
        r.accept(this.vrr);
    }
}
```

`Client` now changes to:

```
public class Client implements Runnable {
    private SelectiveVisitor sv;
    private BlockingQueue<R> q;

    /* . . . */

    @Override
    void run() {
        for (;;) {
            R r = q.take();

            r.accept(sv);
        }
    }
}
```

Each time `r.accept(selectiveVisitor)` is invoked, the `visit` method of the `SelectiveVisitor` class is invoked by one of the subclasses of `BR` and `RR`.

The `visit` method of class `SelectiveVisitor` is overloaded. Every time it's invoked, the most specific version is chosen dynamically, thus the most suitable visitor visits `r`.

---

I'm leaving this post here, just in case somebody stumbles upon a similar design problem in the future, and nothing better has been proposed by then.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of Visitor pattern. Note that here is an interface Visitor with `visit()` methods for each type of visited points.

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
        Point p = new Point2d( 1, 2 );
        Visitor v = new Chebyshev();
        p.accept( v );
        System.out.println( p.getMetric() );
    }
}

interface Visitor {
    public void visit ( Point2d p );
    public void visit ( Point3d p );
}

abstract class Point {
    public abstract void accept ( Visitor v );
    private double metric = -1;
    public double getMetric () {
        return metric;
    }
    public void setMetric ( double metric ) {
        this.metric = metric;
    }
}

class Point2d extends Point {
    public Point2d ( double x, double y ) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void accept ( Visitor v ) {
        v.visit( this );
    }

    private double x;
    public double getX () { return x; }

    private double y;
    public double getY () { return y; }
}

class Point3d extends Point {
    public Point3d ( double x, double y, double z ) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
    public void accept ( Visitor v ) {
        v.visit( this );
    }

    private double x;
    public double getX () { return x; }

    private double y;
    public double getY () { return y; }

    private double z;
    public double getZ () { return z; }
}

class Euclid implements Visitor {
    public void visit ( Point2d p ) {
        p.setMetric( Math.sqrt( p.getX()*p.getX() + p.getY()*p.getY() ) );
    }
    public void visit ( Point3d p ) {
        p.setMetric( Math.sqrt( p.getX()*p.getX() + p.getY()*p.getY() + p.getZ()*p.getZ() ) );
    }
}

class Chebyshev implements Visitor {
    public void visit ( Point2d p ) {
        double ax = Math.abs( p.getX() );
        double ay = Math.abs( p.getY() );
        p.setMetric( ax>ay ? ax : ay );
    }
    public void visit ( Point3d p ) {
        double ax = Math.abs( p.getX() );
        double ay = Math.abs( p.getY() );
        double az = Math.abs( p.getZ() );
        double max = ax>ay ? ax : ay;
        if ( max<az ) max = az;
        p.setMetric( max );
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry, I should have mentioned it in my question. `instanceof` is what I'm trying to avoid here, that's the reason I'm using the enum fields in the first place (I know, it's about the same). Editing question to include this.

Comment: Added new solution, without `instanceof`

Comment: Well, that's exactly the same as the workaround I'm proposing, just uses String instead of enum :) I was looking for something more elegant than this, if anything like this exists.

Comment: I think, it's not needed to cast `r` to `BR` or `RR` because of dynamic linking. You just need to choose `r.accept(vrr)` or `r.accept(vbr)`, right?

Comment: No, cast is needed (for now) first of all because `R` doesn't know anything about the `accept()` method, but most importantly, which one should `R` declare? The one using `VisitorBR` or the one using `VisitorRR`? Or both? None of them, because in this case, one of the classes (`BR` or `RR`) should implement an `accept()` method for the unsuitable visitor.

Comment: Why not to add both of `public abstract void accept(VisitorBR vbr);` and `public abstract void accept(VisitorRR vrr);` to both classes `BR` & `RR`, and then just call `r.accept();` with any visitor you need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107304/discussion-between---and-chrk).